# Adobe Creative SDK API Key Error

Tags: ios, sdk, adobe, image-editing, adobecreativesdk

I have configured adobe image SDK in my IOS APP and i have also pass API KEY and Secret Key but while i call edit image am getting Invalid API or Secret Key error here is my code how am passing API KEY and Secret Key

Error:
`Invalid API Key and Secret`
`Please check to make sure you have correctly entered your API key and secret.`

Code:

```
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

    [[AdobeUXAuthManager sharedManager] setAuthenticationParametersWithClientID:@"5587f31263dc4f38b003dc0a5d9a2e5f" withClientSecret:@"81292c83-eec7-42df-be72-334cbc1d6828"];

});
```

Comment: Hi @Saqib, it would be helpful if you included the specific error message(s) you are getting

Comment: Hi @zhermes Error is Invalid API Key and Secrect Key

Comment: Please paste the ***exact*** error, directly as you get it

Comment: Hi @zhermes i have upload the exact error message screenshot

Comment: Did you got any kind of solutions? I have same issue.